# Flash game doesn't work after obfuscation with SecureSWF 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, obfuscation

I used [SecureSWF](http://www.kindi.com) 4.5 to obfuscate a Flash game. After the obfuscation process, this error came up:

```
>     Warning: The following identifiers' names existed in the protected file(s) while they should have been all renamed. Since you enabled
> Post Build Check, secureSWF is now going to exclude any identifier
> with a similar name to any of the following:
>       MainTimeline__Content__
>       MainTimeline__LoadingAnimation__
>       MainTimeline__Preloader__
>       _mygame_fla
>       __rslPreloader
```

The game is no longer working, it doesn't even start/load anymore. (only the default Flash Player blank screen appears)
Does anybody know how to fix this or can give me an idea what that error means?

(I'm using Flash CS6 and published the game for the Flash Player 11.1)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to not to obfuscate at all. Since ActionScript is a compiled language. Anyway, I google searched something for you...

Maybe you could try another obfuscator.

http://www.ambiera.com/irrfuscator/
http://www.as3gamegears.com/category/obfuscation/

Hope it helps.